# How to import Ionic project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cordova, ionic-framework

I installed the JBOSS Tools for Kepler and included the JBOSS hybrid moblie tools for cordova development and I'm able to create a new functional cordova project.

[image]

---

I can't nonetheless import an existing cordova or ionic project because that option doesn't appear on the eclipse import menu.

[image]

---

Is there a step I missed?

Comment: If you are not bound to Eclipse I can highly recommend [Brackets](http://brackets.io) with [ionic code hinting](https://github.com/chrisgriffith/IonicBrackets). Otherwise you can import the Android project in Eclipse after running `ionic platform add android`.

Comment: Thanks it looks nice but I'm really looking for an IDE and not just a text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I could not solve the problem created when adding the JBOSS Tools for kepler. I then just downloaded the  [Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio 8.1.0](http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/devstudio/luna/8.1.0.GA.html).

It comes armed with a cordova simulator and also supports ionic. Jboss studio is based on eclipse I find it meets my needs.
[image]